# build.gradle.kts - how to set compiler args correctly?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, openapi, micronaut

Got the following content:

```
val commonCompilerArgs = listOfNotNull(
    "-Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop",
)




tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
            freeCompilerArgs = commonCompilerArgs
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
```

But got this error:

Invalid argument: -Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop

I guess it is simple, but I don't know how to set this compiler arguments correctly.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `"-Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop"` is this **one** compiler option, or does the `,` separate multiple options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using kapt in your Micronaut application gradle scripts then you can set it this way:

```kotlin
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg(
            "micronaut.openapi.views.spec",
            "rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop"
        )
    }
}
```

Open API definition files and Swagger UI are generated during annotation processing phase, where source code and resource files are generated. It means that it is before **compileKotlin** task.

Part of example build output:

```
...
> Task :my-app:kaptGenerateStubsKotlin
> Task :my-app:processResources
> Task :my-app:detekt
> Task :my-app:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :my-app:kaptKotlin
Note: Generating OpenAPI Documentation
Note: Writing OpenAPI YAML to destination: /home/me/prj/my-app/backend/build/tmp/kapt3/classes/main/META-INF/swagger/my-app-1.0.yml
Note: Writing OpenAPI View to destination: /home/me/prj/my-app/backend/build/tmp/kapt3/classes/main/META-INF/swagger/views/swagger-ui/index.html
Note: Creating bean classes for 9 type elements

> Task :my-app:compileKotlin
> Task :my-app:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :my-app:classes
...
```

**Update:** You must also add **micronaut.router.static-resources** section for Swagger into *application.yaml* configuration file to map swagger static routes like this:

```yaml
micronaut:
  router:
    static-resources:
      swagger:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger
        mapping: /swagger/**
      swagger-ui:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger/views/swagger-ui
        mapping: /swagger-ui/**
```

Then you can access OpenAPI definition file on http://localhost:8080/swagger/my-app-1.0.yml and Swagger UI should be available on http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui .

Comment: Hmm. It has no effect on my side.  kapt is set as plugin. I also have the openapi.properties configured. OpenApi works if I start it from Intellj directly. But the jar does not provide it.

Comment: I have to correct myself. Your solution IS doing something. It adds the openapi things, but if I load the url for it, it is blank.

Comment: You have to add static route mapping for OpenAPI definition file and Swagger UI. I added example of that into the answer.